# Wordpress "If" statement on advanced custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to echo an error message if no content has been uploaded to my custom post type repeater field.

Some pages will have content and others wont so I just want a simple message saying, sorry we currently have no stock for this artist please come back.

Here is my html:

```
<?php if( have_rows('artist_paintings') ): ?>

    <ul class="slides">

    <?php while( have_rows('artist_paintings') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $thumb_image = get_sub_field('thumbnail');
        ?>

        <li class="slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $thumb_image; ?>" />
        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the below edit, you already have an if statement just use `else` condition for the `if( have_rows('artist_paintings') ):` :

```
<?php if( have_rows('artist_paintings') ): ?>

    <ul class="slides">

    <?php while( have_rows('artist_paintings') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $thumb_image = get_sub_field('thumbnail');
        ?>

        <li class="slide">
        <img src="<?php echo $thumb_image; ?>" />
        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php else: ?>
    <span> sorry we currently have no stock for this artist please come back.</span>
<?php endif;?>
```

without html clean if else example.:

```
if( have_rows('artist_paintings') ):

  // show content if field is not empty

else:

  // show error is field is empty.  

endif;
```

Comment: Perfect. thank you! I knew it would be simple